# Sum of two independent exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Suppose that the time between calls from your aunt Debie has an exponential
distribution with a mean time of 3 days. What is the probability that you will get two calls in less than 3 days?

So trying to solve this I tried to calculate the probability 
$P(X_1+X_2\lt3)$ where $X_1 =$ days to first call and $X_2 = $ days to second call. My attempt to solve...

$$X_1+X_2 \lt 3$$
$$X_1 \lt 3-X_2$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\int_{0}^3\int_{0}^{3-X_2} e^\frac{-x_1+x_2}{3} dx_1dx_2 = 1$$

The probability isn't likely 100% so where did I make my mistake?

Comment: Exponential density with mean $3$ is $\frac13e^{-x/3}$, not $e^{-x/3}$.

Comment: thanks for reminding me, forgot to add my $\frac{1}{9}$ in there

Comment: Next, please explain why you think the RHS is 1.

Comment: Pretty sure $x_2$ should also have a minus sign in the exponent...

Comment: Your mistake seems to be in the integration.  Plus the joint pdf is $\tfrac 1 9 \mathsf e^{-\frac{(x_1+x_2)}{3}}$ (or $\tfrac 1 9\exp\big(-\frac{x_1+x_2}{3}\big)$ to be clearer).

Comment: If you are familiar with the relationship berween the exponential and the Poisson, ou may be able to find a quicker solution.

Comment: Thank you Graham Kemp, that negative was what made it work! If you could post that into an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, what you need to integrate is:

$$\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\leq 3) = \frac 1 9 \int\limits_0^3 e^{-y/3}\left(\int\limits_0^{3-y} e^{-x/3}\operatorname d x\right)\operatorname d y$$

Just take it one step at a time.